# Ansible Create SubFolders Matching Pattern

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible playbook, that creates directories by passed an array of directories, owner, and permissions.   Our admins are worried, someone will create directories under our O/S Volumes and cause issues with the system.   Since we only have a few folders that require root, I'm researching how to whitelist specific folders that are passed in for root only.  Other directories and use our internal user to directories that don't require root.

This is what I've come up with, but I have concern with /vs_volue/etc instead of /etc being passed.  I can't find a starts with /etc for example.   Is there a better way?

```
---
- name: Create Directories
  hosts: target_hosts
  vars:
    dir_list: '{{ dir_list }}'
    permissions: {{ permissions }}
    linux_user: 'webuser'
    whitelist_dir:
      - "/etc"
      - "/usr"

  tasks:
    - name: User to root when creating folders in /etc or /usr
      set_fact:
          linux_user: "root"
      when: dir_list|string|regex_search('{{ item }}')
      with_items:
        - "{{ whitelist_dir }}"

    - name: Create Directories as WebUser by Directory Array Lists by Line Feed
      file:
        path: "{{ item }}"
        mode: "{{ permissions }}"
        recurse: yes
        state: directory
        become: true
        become_user: "{{ linux_user }}"
      with_items: "{{ dir_list.split('\n') }}"
      when: dir_list | search('\n')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

#### main.yml

```
- hosts: target_hosts
  vars:
    default_linux_user: "webuser"
    permissions: "{{ permissions | default(0664) }}"
    whitelist_dir:
      - "^/etc/.*"
      - "^/usr/.*"
  tasks:
    - include_tasks: create_dir.yml
      loop: "{{ dir_list.split('\n') }}"
      loop_control:
         loop_var: dir
```

#### create_dir.yml

```
- block:
    - set_fact:
        linux_user: "{{ 'root' if dir is regex(item) else default_linux_user }}"
      when: linux_user is undefined and (not linux_user == 'root')
      loop: "{{ whitelist_dir }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "For {{ dir }} - {{ linux_user }} will be set as owner"
        
    - file:
        path: "{{ dir }}"
        state: directory
        mode: "{{ permissions }}"
        owner: "{{ linux_user | default(default_linux_user) }}
        recurse: yes
      become: true
      become_user: root
      become_method: sudo
  always:
    - set_fact:
        linux_user: default_linux_user
```

Comment: Instead of `include_tasks` from `create_dir.yml` you can use ansible nested loops as well.

Comment: I'm good with the includes.  I've never used loop_control before.  I'll play with this tomorrow to see if this suits our admin's requirements as well as our own.   I like how it can pass folders for root mixed with normal directories and it only sets root on the correct folders,

Comment: I'm believing this should work, but I'm unable to get it to work..

Comment: Fails the build on - include_tasks: create_dir.yml

Comment: use `-vvv` with `ansible-playbook` command and share what is the exact error.

Comment: I'm unable to do that.   This is through an AaaS "Micro Service" as they call it, which calls ansible.   I did find I could do this to get pass that build issue.      - include: create_dir.yml dir="{{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ dir_list.split('\n') }}"

Comment: However, it then fails stating that whitelist_dir is not defined.   Though it's hardcoded in the playbook.yml, so not sure why yet.

Comment: What ansible version you/they are using?

Comment: Through the UI we can select 2.3 - 2.9

Comment: I'm attempting to use this instead.      - include_tasks: create_dir.yml
      vars:
        dir: "{{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ dir_list.split('\n') }}"

Comment: got closer..    Now I'm getting The conditional check 'linux_user is undefined and (not linux_user = 'root')' failed.  I think that should be a ==, so after approvals and getting it into Dev, I'll know tomorrow.

Comment: Error in File doesn't have become_user or become.   I'm moving it to Owner and Group.

Comment: Basically this is a YAML indentation issue. `become` and `become_user` are not `file` module attributes. Moving them to owner/group won't help. I've corrected the code above.

Comment: Yea, we resolved it with that, but we now find all folders have owner/group of webuser/webusergroup.  Root is never set.    Don't think this works...  linux_user: "{{ 'root' if dir is regex(item) else default_linux_user }}"   I removed the when clause, because I realized that once set to root, any other folder will be forced root.   don't want that.

Comment: I felt that regex wasn't being used correctly here.   I know in other languages regex, needs a pattern.   This is almost like it should be search(), not regex.   I'm still trying.

Comment: I found this..  when: "{{ dir | regex_search('(item)') }}"
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html

Comment: Try printing the `linux_user` value to for each iteration to check if user selection is done properly. Remove `recurse: yes` if you do not want to set ownership recursively, because in case dir's owned by root - will not be operated upon my different user unless explicit permissions are granted.

Comment: I've updated the code above. Try it now. The change is basically perform file operation by root user and update directory owner to value of linux_user. Also added a debug statement that might be helpful to trace linux_user value for each dir during run.

Comment: We are moving away from how this work as it's not working as expected..  I'll be posting a new question, similar to this one, but new logic.